# What will happen to iblees?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, shaitan

On the day of judgement what will happen to iblees?
If he will go to jahanam what will be happen to him when he himself is made of fire?
And why he's having war for a long time with us. Why not he surrender.And what in it for him as he know he don't have a good judgement day?.

Comment: These are a lot of questions which should be treated separately.

Comment: Thank You for reply. What does this mean. Is this question inappropriate?